Run script elevated as different user on remote machine
I have a Windows Scheduled Task that runs a Powershell script file A.ps1. This task runs mostly locally and does NOT need elevation/administrator access. However, a few steps need to run on a remote server and DO need elevation/administrator access. These steps have been isolated to a separate script file B.ps1, on the local server. I will need to provide two arguments to this script file in order to complete it's tasks, that are determined by the A.ps1 script.
The user account running the scheduled task (MYDOMAIN\C) does NOT have administrator access on either the local or the remote server, but I do have credentials for a user on the remote server (MYDOMAIN\D) for a service account that does have the needed admin rights.
I've done most of these things individually many times, but I'm having a hard time stringing ALL of this together so it works as desired. How can I make this work?

If A's output provides values for the arguments but must be run as the scheduled task as the account without elevated permissions, then you might need to have A dump the two values to a text file in a folder A has access either UNC shared on local machine with B having access to it where A dumps it or UNC shared folder on B server where A has write access to it. Then have some routine checking logic in a scheduled task on server B using credential D and get-content or the values for args, process as D, then delete the file so it does not run unless another file exist. Routine or watch works.

This assumes you trust A will always only put values for B for it to read and run routinely, etc. You can lock down shares with SHARE and NTFS so only D and A have access and perhaps make it hidden with appended $ too share wise. You could always give it three values like current run SID, then value1, and value2, then ensure first value always matches SID, <machinename>\UsernameA>, etc. with validation logic in script B that runs then deletes after verification and run sucess. Something crazy like that. If stored creds won't work to all A to run as D type deal with stored cred.

If the problem is about securely storing credentials for B.ps1 then, assuming A.ps1 can safely proceed without waiting for B.ps1 to finish:

Change A.ps1 so that it saves the arguments for B.ps1 to a file in a fixed location.
Change B.ps1 so that it reads the arguments from that file and then deletes it.
Create a scheduled task Task_B that runs B.ps1 as MYDOMAIN\D and set it to run whether user is logged on or not.
Make A.ps1 start Task_B instead of starting B.ps1 directly.


In this case, assume I have a valid PSCredential object and don't worry about where the credentials live.

Oh, and this seems awkward, especially as I may need to do this in a loop a few hundred times, so I'm gonna keep digging. I might adapt it to put all the items in one file and run that part of the loop at the end, but I'm also wary of doing a LOT of work, having this break, and then have a LOT of half-finished tasks. I'm hoping to do better. But it will likely work, so I'll eventually upvote it. However, stack exchange also advantages questions that don't yet have any upvoted answers, and since I want to keep digging I'm gonna wait until I'm back in the office on Monday.
